# How to find angular and linear velocities from word problems

Tags: trigonometry

So I have a couple of word problems here:

1) A paddle wheel in a stream is rotating at $100$rpm. The radius of the paddle wheel is $0.2$ meters. Find the angular speed of the paddle wheel in rad/min.

2) The blades of a saw are $16$ inches in diameter. The saw rotates $900$ rpm. Find the linear speed of the tip of a tooth on the saw in mi/hr (this would equate to how fast a piece of wood could be shot from the saw if an unfortunate circumstance arose...ouch!)

I am asking about the procedure I need to take to find the answer to these problems with the given data.

Comment: Well the first one is asking you to convert units, the second requires the relationship $\omega\cdot r = v$ where omega is the angular speed, r is the radius of the point in question and v is the linear speed of that point.

Comment: Ok @Triatticus, how would I convert rpms to rad/min?

Comment: Rpm or revolutions per minute refers to how many turns of a wheel are in a minute, how many radians are in one turn of any circle?

Comment: Aaaah yes, I see, 2 pi radians per revolution. thanks @Triatticus

Comment: Yep {}{}{}{}{}{}{}